# Slider Range between 0 and 1 with step 0.05

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a slider range function having minimum and maximum value between 0 and 1 with step 0.05. Default value, is set to be at 0.65 and 0.85. But with 0 and 1, its not working properly. Between 0 and 100 its working

**Working Code with range between 0 and 100**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [65,85],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#min-val").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#max-val").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#min-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)));
    $("#max-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)));
```

**Code for between 0 and 1(not working)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        values: [0.65, 0.75],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#min-val").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#max-val").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#min-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)));
    $("#max-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the version that is *not* working. It seems you have given the one that works.

Comment: @trincot added with question. Thanks

Comment: Please specify exactly which slider plugin you are using.  Looks like the one you have only works with integers.

Comment: Why not use an HTML5 element? `<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="3" id="rangeSlider" step=".5">`

Comment: @freedomn-m its jquirtude

Comment: @Zak, that doesn't create the double-sided range widget that jQueryUI offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not use the `step` property. Once added it works fine:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        values: [.65,.85],
        step: .05,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#min-val").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#max-val").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#min-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)));
    $("#max-val").val(($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot. Please upvote the question too...